Prioritizing scheduling with Kubernetes
I have a case where I create 1000 low-priority pods on 20 nodes (one pod can run on one node), to run all 1000 pods will take a few days. Meanwhile, I want to run another high-priority pod and ensure it will run before the next lower-priority pods (once a node is freed, without killing other pods).
Reading K8s documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/), it seems that the solution described here should work like a charm (using preemptionPolicy: Never).
What is unclear to me is the following paragraph "This means that if the scheduler tries these pods and they cannot be scheduled, they will be retried with lower frequency, allowing other pods with lower priority to be scheduled before them."
Does this mean that low-priority jobs might run BEFORE high-priority jobs? Is there any solution to ensure that higher priority will run first?
Thank you
